# Google A Variable In Web Scene Using TASKER

Tags: javascript, android, tasker

I have read a screen using TouchTask ie. %user1 And now I have created a scene - webview1 , URL - www.google.com
I want to Google %user1 in that webview1 Is it possible using tasker?

Comment: I'm not sure that Tasker uses either JavaScript or S...

Comment: It uses JavaScript and SL4A...